# Download pdf with Selenium from javascript pop-up

Tags: python, selenium

this is my first question here, please don't be mean :)

I'm trying to download all the SDSs (are in pdf format) from [here](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/search?term=barium&interface=All&N=0&mode=match%20partialmax&lang=en&region=US&focus=product).

At first I've tried with requests and BeautifulSoup but the pdf pop-up from Javascript, then using Selenium  but it didn't work.
So far my code it's the following and I don't know what to do next.

```
from selenium import webdriver
pdf_url= "http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/MSDS/MSDS/DisplayMSDSPage.do?country=US&language=en&productNumber=474711&brand=ALDRICH&PageToGoToURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sigmaaldrich.com%2Fcatalog%2Fproduct%2Faldrich%2F474711%3Flang%3Den"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(pdf_url)    
driver.find_element_by_name("msdsPageFrame").get_attribute("src")
```

Comment: Do you want to save document as `PDF` file or just to get text content of each document?

Comment: I want to save them as pdf.